# Cannot export 'Buffer'. Only local declarations can be exported from a module. Why this Message rising?

Tags: typescript, types, buffer

> Compiled with problems:
>
> ERROR
>
> node_modules/@types/node/ts4.8/buffer.d.ts:98:14 - error TS2661: Cannot export 'Buffer'. Only local declarations can be exported from a module.
>
> 98     export { Buffer };

This happened when installed after this

```
npm install pouchdb @types/pouchdb
```

what is the solution to this problem?

I tried this
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26086

Comment: `skipLibCheck: true`?

Comment: in compileroptions?